# Looking for JPG image to PDF converter

Tags: pdf, google-drive, jpg

I want an application that will:

1. Use pictures I've already taken of documents
2. Remove the background
3. Transform the image to be the right shape for a document
4. Convert it to PDF

Preferably it should:

- Run on Windows 10
- Be FOSS

Essentially a desktop version of Google Drive Scan to PDF.

Comment: For which desktop? What OS must it run on? And does your wish for open-source also imply free-of-charge? And it should basically do what [unpaper](https://www.flameeyes.eu/projects/unpaper) does (those of us not using GDrive might be unaware of what the mentioned "Drive Scan" does – so we'll need your requirements listed explicitly, see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185))?

Comment: You can check Adobe Lens (for mobile) to combine the process of take photo and convert it to pdf

Comment: @Izzy Updated to address your comment. Unpaper looks like it might be close to what I need from reading their documentation, but it doesn't support JPG files. The drive scan reference is a summary of the ask.

Comment: Hm, maybe pipelining could work: `imagetops` takes an image and turns it into a postscript file, which could be converted to PDF using `ps2pdf`. Combined: `imagetops image.jpg | ps2pdf - image.pdf` (if `unpaper` accepts input from STDIN, replace `image.pdf` by another `-` and pipe that to unpaper). Not sure about the quality of that, though – so hopefully there are better options. Luckily, my scanner software directly creates PDF files which I then can process using [pdfsandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/), which a.o. utilizes unpaper…

Comment: Single JPG image to PDF converter, or batch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "remove the background" but I use [File Converter](https://www.file-converter.org) for conversions. Works on image, video and audio files. I just checked .jpg and it converted to .pdf like expected. It can't crop the image, but that can be done easily in several native Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ilovepdf](https://www.ilovepdf.com). It contains every tool you need to use PDFs, at your fingertips. All are 100% FREE and easy to use! Merge, split, compress, convert, rotate, unlock and watermark PDFs with just a few clicks.

However, if you're yet to take a snapshot of the documents, you can use google lens on your mobile phone to capture the texts. Then, save and transfer the file to your desktop and convert to pdf.